# Find and Replace words from an entire project

Tags: texmaker, find

I'm wrapping up my phd thesis and there are some words, that I would like to replace in the whole project. Let's say e.g. change all "data-base" to "database".

I use Texmaker and of course I can go manually through all files and hit the find and replace button. However, for 10 .tex documents (chapters and appendices) and about 15 words, this is too lengthy. Is there the possibility to do this for all documents at once?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a global search-and-replace operation across all open files?

Comment: Yes. to put it in other words that's exactly it.

Comment: Using `epsilon` editor, your requirement is easily to fix, but not sure about `TeXmaker`...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251742/34224

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to solve it with the commandline:

```
sed -i 's/data-sources/data sources/g' *.tex
```

Comment: Interesting. Without using the command line, there is the option to use NotePad++, `search in Files` (I think there one similar in Matlab). It makes a little bit more "human-friendly" to do it and is the option I suggest when talking to people "not used to command-line" (I was one of them for a long time).

Comment: On the other hand, I wrote a simple Matlab function to [Search and Replace](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61226-search-and-replace-a-wordset-library) a given set of words into another set in given set of files. It is helpful to reuse the same replacements again or to automatize when more than one word is replaced, specially if the orders matters.